# Combining rand() numbers

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to combine a few random numbers. The numbers are supposed to represent a dice.

For example, I want to roll the dice 5 times and I get the following results:
**4 2 1 4 6**.
These are all individual numbers but what I want to do is **combine it together as 42146**.

This might be a very simple question so I apologize for that but I'm still new to Ruby.

I'm generating numbers between [1,6] through this:

```
number = 1 + rand(6)
```

Comment: This is less random than `Random.rand(99999) + 1` since you only have 1-6 in each base-10 slot with your method. Why do that?

Comment: @CodeGnome: Yes clearly it generates only some numbers out of all possible 5-digit numbers, but I'm not sure I would call that "less random" (but just a technicality). I suspect OP wants to generate a random string of digits and doesn't really want or need an Integer result at the end. However, it could be they want to represent a result from a game like Yahtzee - in which case the combined String (or Integer) may not be the most useful representation. May be worth clarifying, but also if it gets complicated at that point, could be a separate question . . .

Answer (score 4):

```
1.upto(5).map { rand(1..6) }.join.to_i
```

- [`1.upto(5)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto) will give you an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) for 5 elements
- `map { rand(1..6) }` will [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) a random number [between 1 and 6](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) to each of the above elements
- [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) will concatenate all elements of what you got so far
- [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) will transform the above result from string to integer

Comment: One might use `5.times` instead of `1.upto(5)`. Otherwise, nice beginner-friendly code.

Comment: @D-side, I tend to use `times` for iteration and `upto` for mapping. It makes more sense when reading. Otherwise, it sounds like you want to do the mapping 5 times, not that you want to map something to 5 items.

Comment: My concern is that the given code should be executed 5 times, specifying iteration from 1 to 5 seems like exposing an implementation detail to me. Yours is a valid point too. Maybe that's the reason why Ruby also has `collect` as a synonym of `map`. Well, that's enough bikeshedding for today, I guess :}

Answer (score 1):

Although all the answers are correct, there is one more option:

```
dice = 0

5.times do
    dice = dice * 10 + rand(1..6)
end

puts dice
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/WfagFT
This time you **treat everything as integers**. Everytime (5 rolls) you take the result variable, multiply it by 10 and then add new random number at the end of it. There's no need to use anything else for that.

Of course if you need it, this code can be also written as one-liner  and do exactly the same as above:

```
p @dice if 5.times { @dice = @dice.to_i * 10 + rand(1..6) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
5.times.inject(0){|n, _| n * 10 + 1 + rand(6)}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your doing? I'm a beginner to Ruby so I don't know much unfortunately

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby but it looks as if he is treating the numbers as strings and just concatenating them (which is adding to strings together for "ran" concatenated with "dom" is "random".

Answer (score 0):

```
p Array.new(5){1 + rand(6)}.join # => "53325"
```